# Entity type not found when editing contents

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a model which contains multiple users. The relationship between Users and Project is a many-to-many. EF Core has auto-generated a third table to account for this. I am trying to allow the user to edit the project and one of the editing properties is to remove a user. I would appreciate any insight into what might be causing this error and how I should handle `List` changes. I have been handling editing features by placing a `EntityState.Modified` on the value before saving which has worked out well until now. Thanks in advance!

I keep running into this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'List<ApplicationUser>' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.GetOrCreateEntry(Object entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Entry[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at WebApp.Server.Controllers.ProjectsController.PutProject(Guid id, Project project) in C:\Users\Shahb\source\repos\WebApp\WebApp\Server\Controllers\ProjectsController.cs:line 78
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at WebApp.Server.Startup.<>c.<<Configure>b__5_0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Shahb\source\repos\WebApp\WebApp\Server\Startup.cs:line 98
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService events, IBackChannelLogoutService backChannelLogoutService)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapWhenMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The problem seems to occur with the following line in the controller

```
_context.Entry(project.AssignedUsersToProject).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

This would be to make the db aware of a modification to the original information

### Removing users function

```
    private void RemoveUser(string username) {

    var user = projectItem.AssignedUsersToProject.First(n => n.UserName.Equals(username));

    projectItem.AssignedUsersToProject.Remove(user);    
}
```

### Project model

```
 public class Project {
        [Key]
        public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ProjectName { get; set; } 

        public bool isComplete { get; set; } = false;

        public ICollection<ApplicationUser> AssignedUsersToProject { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using entities that are being tracked by EF, then you can just remove it from the list.

If the entities are not being tracked and you are manually attaching and setting EntityState then handling a many to many when the join entity is not in the model is a challenge.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/251966/ef-core-5-many-to-many-disconected-addremove-witho.html

The reason you are getting the error is because you are passing a List into context.Entry.  EF understands ApplicationUser but not List< ApplicationUser >.  That's a different 'type'.

Comment: EF makes the join table automatically when a many-to-many relationship is defined. Would I have to go through this table and remove the user from the join table which will then remove them from the list correctly?